# CSS radial gradient crashes FireFox

Tags: html, css

I am using radial gradients to create a dotted background style for my website. The radial gradient that I use in my CSS works fine in Chrome, but when I load the same webpage in FireFox, it crashes the browser, meaning that the browser does not respond and I have to use Task Manager to close it down.

The CSS which I think causes the problem:

```
/* The background is coloured #97cdcd (blue), and the radial-gradient creates the dots which are placed 
    on top of the background. */
body{
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(#a8d4e1 15%, transparent 16%),
                -moz-radial-gradient(#a8d4e1 15%, transparent 16%),
                #99c9d3;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#a8d4e1 15%, transparent 16%),
                -webkit-radial-gradient(#a8d4e1 15%, transparent 16%),
                #99c9d3;
                background-color: #97cdcd;
    background-position: 0 0, 80px 80px;
     -moz-background-size:7px 7px;
    -webkit-background-size:7px 7px;
    background-size: 7px 7px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the radial gradient... It renders fine on FF (18.0.1)

Comment: I am using FF 18.0.1. If you try and put the CSS from above in an bare-bones HTML file and run it in FF, it still crashes

Comment: Maybe an add-on causes the crash? you can try to disable all of your add-ons and then re-enabling them one by one.

Comment: No I don't think its that. I tried this at home, and at my university, and still got the same result.

Comment: It doesn't crash with FF18 on Linux, and... it doesn't work too, I don't see any radial gradient, just a uniform bacgkround...

Comment: I will bet on one add-on too... try starting Firefox in Safe Mode (add-on disabled) and run your site...

Comment: Hey Andrea Ligios I tried running the site in Safe Mode, and site loaded without any problems. So if it is an add-on that is causing this issue, which one do you think it might be? I am not a FF user so I have downloaded no add-ons for the browser. I just need FF for testing browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not a FF user so I have downloaded no add-ons for the browser. I just need FF for testing browser compatibility.

Being a month-old question, I'm guessing this issue has been resolved. However, if you want to access your Extensions and Plugins in Firefox simply:

1. Click on `Firefox` in the top right corner.
2. Click on "Add-ons"
3. From there you can view your Extensions and Plugins.

Chances are that as you're not a Firefox user you probably won't have any Extensions installed. You will, however, more than likely have some Plugins related to certain programs you have installed on your computer.

> So if it is an add-on that is causing this issue, which one do you think it might be?

You can disable any Extensions or Plugins you may have by clicking on the `Disable` button to the left of it's name. This does not cause anything to be deleted, so if you needed to you could simply disable them all and then re-enable them all at a later date.